# Change whole app background

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have taken a imageview in **applicationDidFinishLaunching** as shown below.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
      self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
      UIImageView* imageBg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
      imageBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppBG.png"];
       [self.window addSubview:imageBg];
       [self.window sendSubviewToBack:imageBg]; 
 }
```

Now In **rootViewController** I  have one button

My need is that on **press of button** in **RootViewController** I want to change the image from AppBG.png to AppBG1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `UIImageView`, `imageBg` an property, synthesize it.

Then Use following code on button click:

```
MyAppdelegate *appdelegate = (MyAppdelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appdelegate.imageBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppBG1.png"];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//add a tag to your imageview
imageBg.tag = 1001;

//fetch the imageview from window like this
UIImageView *imgView = [self.window viewWithTag:1001];

//use this imageView to replace existing image like this
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newimg.png"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy! Just make `imageBg` a local property and instance in the AppDelegate. Don't forget to synthesize your properties. And in RootViewController class put this code in a button `IBAction` that is connected to a `UIButton`:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed {
AppDelegate *delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
delegate.imageBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"AppBG1.png"];
// Don't forget memory management!
[delegate release];
}
```

Another method you could do this is add a method in the app delegate:

```
- (void)changeImage {

 self.imageBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"AppBG1.png"];
}
```

And in RootViewController call this method:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed {
AppDelegate *delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
[delegate changeImage];
// Don't forget memory management!
[delegate release];
}
```

Just simple Objective-C!